# File Upload file button for all values working as one

Tags: html, angular

I have a list of values to be displayed each having an upload button, file upload is working properly but the issue I am facing is, when I click on upload button for any list the upload is working for the first list.

Below is my code.

HTML

```
 <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let question of Questions">
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-2">
                        <h4 class="chapter">{{question.topic}} - {{question.id}}</h4>
                        <div>
                            <input type="file" id="file" class="ml-2" (change)="uploadAnswers($event, question.id, question.topic)">
                        <label for="file">
                            Upload Answers
                        <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I make sure to make the upload button unique to its list?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here in the snippet there is only one list. Does your application have other lists as well similar to this one ?

Comment: @vj I am having a for loop for ul element

Comment: The code is creating a new list for every list item -- a series of lists with a single item each. Typically one puts the `*ngFor` on the `li` so that you get a single `ul` with multiple `li`s...

Comment: Also, ids must be unique to the document, so `id="file"` isn't going to work. Maybe `id="file-{{question.id}}"`? Please include the code for `uploadAnswers` as well.

Comment: id="file-{{question.id}}", after adding this the button isn't working

Answer (score 0):

And what if you put *ngFor in li element?

```js
<ul class="list-group">
  <li *ngFor="let question of Questions" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-2">
    <h4 class="chapter">{{question.topic}} - {{question.id}}</h4>
      <div>
        <input type="file" id="file" class="ml-2" (change)="uploadAnswers($event, question.id, question.topic)">
        <label for="file">
          Upload Answers
          <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </label>
        </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the same thing is happening

Comment: Could you check the given attributes with console.log() in uploadAnswers() method? `console.log(event), console.log(id), console.log(topic)`

Comment: yeah I have checked that, we are getting the first list values

Answer (score 0):

All of your file input buttons have the same "id"  and "for" value.  Make them unique by adding the question.id, like this stack example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zjbr32?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```html
 <div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
      <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let question of Questions">
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-2">
              <h4 class="chapter">{{question.topic}} - {{question.id}}</h4>
              <div>
                  <input type="file" [id]="'file-'+question.id" class="ml-2" (change)="uploadAnswers($event, question.id, question.topic)">
              <label [for]="'file-'+question.id">
                  Upload Answers
              <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would have been my second answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

issue is all inputs have same id "**file**" and all labels are bind to just one input Id so when ever u click on any label it raise event to first input

here is solution each input has unique id and each label is bind to its unique input Id

```
 <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let question of Questions">
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-2">
                        <h4 class="chapter">{{question.topic}} - {{question.id}}</h4>
                        <div>
                            <input type="file" [id]="'question' + question.id" class="ml-2" (change)="uploadAnswers($event, question.id, question.topic)">
                        <label [for]="'question' + question.id">
                            Upload Answers
                        <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have replicated ur example and now its working

[image]